# New way to integrate aar in Android Studio. How

Tags: android, android-studio, unityads

I face with the problem. I can't to integrate aar. In particular the unity-ads.aar file. I don't understand their tutorial. See

[image]

I try to do the same, but I can't.

What I made uncorrectly?

[image]

Can you help me please. Can you provide screenshots step by step please to integrate aar file In particular Unity Ads. Thanks!

Comment: I finally found another way integration implementation 'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.0.0'

Comment: First copy your sdk into libs folder `app -> libs`. Then add this line to your app level gradle file inside dependencies. `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])`